# cannot use 'new' on the reference type; use 'gcnew' instead

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, c++-cli

I'm trying to use this code:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click_1(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    // Displays an OpenFileDialog so the user can select a Image.
    OpenFileDialog^ OpenFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog1->Filter = "Images|*.jpg";
    openFileDialog1->Title = "Choose Image";

    // Show the Dialog.
    // If the user clicked OK in the dialog and
    // a file was selected, change picture.
    if (openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK){
        pictureBox1->Image = Image::FromFile(openFileDialog1->FileName);
    }
}
```

I wrote this code from msdn documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/61097ykx(v=vs.110).aspx

But i get errors:

> Error 1   error C2750: 'System::Windows::Forms::OpenFileDialog' : cannot use 'new' on the reference type; use 'gcnew' instead
>
> Error 2   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'System::Windows::Forms::OpenFileDialog *' to 'System::Windows::Forms::OpenFileDialog ^'

How it can be solved?

Comment: I have removed the C++ tag and added the tags C++-CLI and Winforms. This is C++/CLI code and *not* C++. There are many differences, such as `gcnew` for garbage collected objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is very helpful here. Use `gcnew` instead:

```
OpenFileDialog^ OpenFileDialog1 = gcnew OpenFileDialog();
                                  ^^^^^^
```

`new` is for pointers, `gcnew` is for garbage collected objects (hence `gc`).